# TFS Builds failing to find _PublishedWebsites/Web.Config

Tags: tfsbuild, alm

After moving source to a different collection (one team project for all files), and manually re-creating the builds I am getting the following build error.

`C:\b\1\1\src\Src\Case\Case.UI\Case.UI.csproj(803,5): error : Could not write Destination file: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\b\1\1\src\Src\Case\Case.UI\bin\_PublishedWebsites\Case.UI\Web.config'.`

This only applies when using the MS-Build args:

`/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:TransformConfigFiles=True`

The line in question is 'apparently' to do with Web.config transforms (Which we do require), and links back to the project file here:

`<TransformXml Source="Web.config" Transform="$(ProjectConfigTransformFileName)" Destination="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\Web.config" />`

Comment: Did you check to see if that path is being created during the build? Is $(WebProjectOutputDir) pointing to the expected place?

Comment: The path is created, but it contains a zip file - how would I check the expected path?

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce the problem on your local machine? That is always the fastest, best way. Build from the command line and increase the build verbosity (msbuild /? - /flp:verbosity=diagnostic) should help. Or simply up the build logging verbosity in your TFS build to see what it's actually doing. Look at the MSBuild log file rather than the TFS build log file will probably be best. That log file will contain the details of what's going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is MSBUILD attempting to transform your config files in the wrong directory.

Remove the argument /p:TransformConfigFiles=True and just have it set to do the transform in the solution itself.

Answer (score 2):

try to remove $(WebProjectOutputDir) from Destination:

```
<TransformXml Source="Web.config" Transform="$(ProjectConfigTransformFileName)" Destination="Web.config" />
```